# cpu interchangability

Tags: cpu

Can i replace an Amd Athlon(tm) XP 2000+ with a Pentium 4 cpu out of an old Dell? The Amd is in a functioning Compaq desktop....

Comment: ...not programming, but the answer is no.

Answer (score 12):

No. AMD Athlon XP's use a different socket type (Socket A (462)) while the Pentium 4 uses socket 478.

Comment: It is the right website now :) Please put meta-comments like that in comments, not answers, and remember that there's the option to migrate...

Comment: @bdonlan: fixed now. :)

Answer (score 2):

There hasn't been a standard CPU socket design since before the Pentium II. Intel moved to the Slot 1 while AMD made gradual improvements to socket 7. Then AMD tried their own Slot A design. Eventually both abandoned the Slot idea and went back to sockets but there hasn't a cross compatible socket design since 1994.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the P4 into the AMD's motherboard, no.  But you might be able to migrate the P4+motherboard (and maybe +RAM as well) from the Dell case into the Compaq.  If you end up considering that, also consider that it might be simpler to migrate the components from the Compaq into the Dell's case.